# GRUB Windows won’t boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

I’m using Parrot OS in dual boot with Windows 10. One day Windows just stopped booting from GRUB with next error:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a034d0,0)/PCI(1,1)/PCI(0,0)/UnknownMessaging(17)/HD(1,800,32000,f452754febf9674d,2,2)
/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire 
error: cannot load image.
```

I have tried using boot-repair to fix this but it didn’t help. Here is its log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6SXYdWxwxh/

When I try to boot Windows directly from BIOS, the screen just blinks for a second and nothing happens. Linux is working fine.

Secure boot in BIOS is set to off.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome  But probably a Windows issue as grub only boots working Windows. And often just Windows update turned fast startup back on which sets hibernation flag or Windows did UEFI update resetting some UEFI settings. Check all settings.

Comment: The problem is that I can’t boot up my Windows instance to access settings.

Comment: @hello_world That may be, but this question is still [off-topic on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). That page lists other places where you can get help. But not here. I'm sorry, but you're not allowed to ask about Parrot OS here.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @hello_world Did you find any solution ? I'm also facing the same issue. Please share the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to find other solution than reinstalling Windows.